# RH side of the Uncertainty principle: when is it a number and when an expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

The [uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) between the position $x$ and the momentum $p$ is given by: $$ \sigma_x \sigma_p \geq \hbar/2,$$  whereas for the $x$ and $y$ components of the angular momentum is given by:
$$ \sigma_{L_x} \sigma_{L_y} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}\langle L_z\rangle .$$

What is the physical meaning of the Right Hand Side being just a number or an expectation value?

EDIT: I realise the expectation value itself is just a number, but it can take several different values, as opposed to a constant

Comment: An expectation value is just a number.

Comment: Yeah I but it can vary, I meant as opposed to just a constant

Comment: I still don't understand what the question is, then. The thing on the right in your first equation is also just an expectation value - that of a multiple of the identity.

Comment: @SuperCiocia   it can vary only if you pass from one state to another state. The quantities $\sigma$ on the LHS don't vary from state to state? The same with the RHS. I your first inequality you have on the RHS a number. But in the 2nd inequality you have a ***variable***, which is state-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle in the most general form
$$\Delta_\omega(A)\Delta_\omega(B)\geq\frac12|\omega([A,B])|$$
depends on the state $\omega$ on which it is evaluated. In the special case of the canonical commutation relations $[q,p]= i\hbar I$, $\omega(I)=1$ for any state and therefore the RHS reduces to a constant. For more general commutators however this won't be the case and a dependence on the state $\omega$ will remain.

Comment: Is there a physical meaning if the uncertainty does not depend on the state?

Answer (score 2):

The uncertainty product is bounded from below by the expectation value of the commutator of the relevant observables. If $A$ and $B$ are any two observables, then the generalized Heisenberg uncertainty relation reads as 
$$ \sigma_A\sigma_B \geq \frac{1}{2}\vert \langle[A,B]\rangle\vert .$$
For the case of position - linear momentum pair, the commutator is $[x,p]=i\hbar$ and so the right-hand side of the inequality above becomes independent of the state.

Comment: Is there a physical meaning if the uncertainty does not depend on the state?